# Fetch Data from multiple Entities with no relationship between them

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, ios7

I have to fetch data from multiple entities which are associated to different screens of an iPhone App, now the scenario is as follows, when user press a Sync button i will have to fetch data from all these entities (i have about 12 entities) and send all this data to a server via a web service, and all these entities have no relationship among them, now my question is what is the best approach to do this task, should i write 12 different fetch requests in a single method, or is there some other better approach, if any one can guide with some tutorial link, that will me most appreciated, thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a for loop to accomplish your task like this. I've used this code to delete all entries of the Database.

```
NSArray *allEntities = [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectModel] entities];
NSError *error;
for (NSEntityDescription *entityDescription in allEntities)
{
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entityDescription];

    fetchRequest.includesPropertyValues = NO;
    fetchRequest.includesSubentities = NO;

    NSArray *items = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error requesting items from Core Data: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }

    //Do whatever you need to do here
}
```

Comment: This items array will be containing what? all entities?? and what are these 2 lines doing? fetchRequest.includesPropertyValues = NO;
    fetchRequest.includesSubentities = NO;

Comment: No, items will contains all the objects of a single entity. But since you are running a for loop, in the next iteration it will contain all objects of another entity.

Comment: ok, but how do i know that currently items is containing which specific entity, Entity A, B or C, which entity?, so that i can get data of that specific entity.

Comment: [entityDescription name]; will give you the name of entity.